# javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake while load Test using JMeter

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I am doing the load test using JMeter of my web application which is hosted on tomcat 7 with SSL configured.

My load test is working fine for 100,200,300,500 https get requests, URL is below:

https://testapi.myapp.com/myapptor/tempo/getinfo?id=4E92D41E&groupid=test

But when i m trying to put more load say 600 or greater than 600 requests, I am getting below error as response for some of the get requests whereas some of the get request having the correct response data:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:294)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.MeasuringConnectionManager$MeasuredConnection.open(MeasuringConnectionManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:643)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:479)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:906)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:805)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:517)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:331)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:74)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1146)
    at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1135)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.process_sampler(JMeterThread.java:434)
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:261)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
    ... 20 more
```

Can you please advice me, why I am getting above error and who is that Remote host mentioned in error?

My tomcat server have max threads to 300 and accept count to 100.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly the kind of thing that starts happening when the load is too great for your system. 'Remote host' means the tomcat instance.

Either accept that 500 connections is the most your system will handle, or start investigating scaling up.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bug in Tomcat that has recently been fixed. Please have a look at [this bug report](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57931) and see if it matches your issue.